# After changing package name Youtube API is not working

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am creating an application using Youtube API. It was working fine but after i change the package name using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) I am getting below exception.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
```

If i change package name back to original with same method the API start to work fine.

I have been changed the `applicationId` to new package name, restart Android Studio, clean project, rebuiled project but nothing changes.

**Stack Track:**

```
11-09 01:49:38.903 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
11-09 01:49:38.903 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:299)
11-09 01:49:38.903 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
11-09 01:49:38.903 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
11-09 01:49:38.903 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.example.nishant.veuz.youTubeOperations.YouTubeChannelVideo$2.doInBackground(YouTubeChannelVideo.java:92)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.example.nishant.veuz.youTubeOperations.YouTubeChannelVideo$2.doInBackground(YouTubeChannelVideo.java:88)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzy(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.904 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
11-09 01:49:38.905 10201-10610/com.example.nishant.veuz W/System.err:   ... 12 more
```

Comment: What package did you change?  What's your project's packages?

Comment: yes, i changed `com.example.nishant.myTube` to `com.example.nishant.views`

Comment: Somehow I doubt that changing your package responsibly would cause an auth exception. Post your **full** stack trace.

Comment: If you change your package name (ApplicationId) you most likely need to generate a new token or key to communicate with the API. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register#Create_API_Keys

Comment: @Makoto added stack track

Comment: @AChez9 thanks, i totally forgot that API also needs the package name. thank you very much.